# Website doesn't load properly in Safari browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, safari

This is my website: http://themescreators.com/seven-host/

I am using a custom loading effect and for some reason it doesn't work well.

This is the code used on the loading effect:

HTML:

```
<div class="loadingContainer">
   <div class="loading">
      <div class="rect1"></div>
      <div class="rect2"></div>
      <div class="rect3"></div>
      <div class="rect4"></div>
      <div class="rect5"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.loadingContainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.loadingContainer .loading {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.loadingContainer .loading > div {
  background-color: #21242e;
  height: 80px;
  width: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.loadingContainer .loading .rect2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}
.loadingContainer .loading .rect3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
  animation-delay: -1s;
}
.loadingContainer .loading .rect4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}
.loadingContainer .loading .rect5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}
.loading i {
  width: 52px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -21px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -30px;
  font-size: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

JS:

```
  jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery('.loadingContainer').css({'opacity' : 0 , 'display' : 'none'});
  });
```

In Safari the ".loadingContainer" isn't removed after the page is loaded, so you only see all the page blank.
Can somebody help me fixing this?

Comment: [I can't reproduce the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/sm4sw60e/), and that code does not appear to be at the link.

Comment: can you please tell me you using safari in window?

Comment: did you install quick time player?

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. It behaves in Safari just like it does in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `jQuery(window).load(function(){`with the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Fadeout the screen when the page is fully loaded
    $('.loadingContainer').fadeOut();
});
```

As far as I know there is no need to specify jquery in the code. In my example jquery will automatically handle the `fadeOut()` handler. The rest of the code can be handled by the core Javascript. I also use this code in my website, and it works flawlessly on every operating system (even android).

Comment: Actually, WordPress is using jQuery in noConflict() mode by default, so unless you use anonymous function and provide the $ as a jQuery alias inside you will get a type error.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your issue. Perhaps did you remove the "loadingcontainer" from your site?

To say about your code, you will need to define the "stretchdelay" animation.

```
@keyframes stretchdelay {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes stretchdelay {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;} 
}
```